# How to iterate over a CHAR_INFO struct without using static int

Tags: c++, windows

When using a for-loop to iterate over a CHAR_INFO struct (windows.h) I seem to only be able to use an `static int`, like so:

Working code:

```cpp
const int MAP_SIZE = 45;
CHAR_INFO map[MAP_SIZE];
static int TILE_CENTER = 22;

for (static int j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
   map[j].Char.UnicodeChar = (j == TILE_CENTER ? tiles[0].getAsciiChar() : L'▓');
   map[j].Attributes = 0x20;
}
```

This offcourse is not a clean solution, but whenever i use an unsigned or regular int the program crashes, no compiler errors (that would be awesome), it just crashes.

Code that crashes:

```cpp
const int MAP_SIZE = 45;
CHAR_INFO map[MAP_SIZE];

const int TILE_CENTER = 22;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        map[j + (i * 9)].Char.UnicodeChar = (j == TILE_CENTER ? tiles[0].getAsciiChar() : L' ');
        map[j + (i * 9)].Attributes = 0x20;
    }
}
```

I looked into creating an iterator of type CHAR_INFO, but without succes.

Is there a way to avoid using `static int` in this case?

### Minimal Reproducible Example

(Compiled with g++)

```cpp
#include "windows.h"

int main(void) {
    while (true) {
        const int MAP_SIZE = 45;
        CHAR_INFO map[MAP_SIZE];

        int TILE_CENTER = 22;

        for (int j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
            map[j].Char.UnicodeChar = (j == TILE_CENTER ? 'X' : L' ');
            map[j].Attributes = 0x20;
        }

        COORD coordinateBufferSize;
        COORD topLeftCoordinate;
        PSMALL_RECT srcWriteRect;

        coordinateBufferSize.Y = 5;
        coordinateBufferSize.X = 9;

        topLeftCoordinate.Y = 0;
        topLeftCoordinate.X = 0;

        srcWriteRect->Top = 4;
        srcWriteRect->Left = 10;
        srcWriteRect->Bottom = 8;
        srcWriteRect->Right = 18;

        HANDLE oldScreenBuffer = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        HANDLE newScreenBuffer = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL,
            CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
            NULL);

        BOOL succes = WriteConsoleOutputW(
            newScreenBuffer,                    // The new ScreenBuffer
            map,                                // The char array we want to display
            coordinateBufferSize,               // 
            topLeftCoordinate,
            srcWriteRect
        );

        SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(newScreenBuffer);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The error i get when debugging:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00401491 in main () at mre.cpp:25
25              srcWriteRect->Top = 4;
```

Comment: Code works for me, please elaborate...

Comment: What sort of "crash" do you get? Present your [mcve] so that we can see. The problem is 99.9999% certainly not in the code you showed us, so we cannot help you.

Comment: In the first code-block i use 'static int' and i think it was clear this indeed works fine. The problem is that i don't wantto use 'static int' i don't want my iteration variable to be accessible during the entire program... I added the code that crashes now if that makes things clearer. Thanks

Comment: And whoever gave me a down vote, feel free to elaborate on why. Was I not clear the presented code works fine but that i am looking for a 'cleaner' alternative? If there's something else wrong with my question, i would like to know, so i don't make the same mistake again. Thanks

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings What do you mean 'what sort of crash" ? I click the .exe file, the console window opens up, stays black for a second, then it closes (a program crash, no output).

Comment: @Michael Indeed, as i mentioned, when using 'static in' it indeed works... that's not the problem. I just run into problems when iterating over multiple of these loops when i can't use regular 'int'.

Comment: @MaximVA When that happens, you should be running your program through a debugger to get information on the crash. Like a reason/cause, and a backtrace. Neither you nor we can do anything with just "it crashes"! Are you working on the [mcve] yet?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I added a Minimal reproducible example, when i debug i get this error:
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00401491 in main () at mre.cpp:25
25              srcWriteRect->Top = 4;

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Thanks to you pointing me to the debugger i found the answer myself. I posted an answer with the correct code. Thanks again.

Comment: A valuable lesson here! :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meanwhile i found the answer:

The problem was the `PSMALL_RECT` type i used for the srcWriteRect variable.
Apparently this pointed to unavailble memory and crashed the program.

The type should be `SMALL_RECT` and any assignments should be made to a pointer to this variable.

### Working example (with the altered code)

```cpp
#include "windows.h"

int main(void) {
    while (true) {
        const int MAP_SIZE = 90;
        CHAR_INFO map[MAP_SIZE];

        int TILE_CENTER = 22;

        for (int j = 0; j < 45; j++) {
            map[j].Char.UnicodeChar = (j == TILE_CENTER ? 'X' : L' ');
            map[j].Attributes = 0x20;
        }

        COORD coordinateBufferSize;
        COORD topLeftCoordinate;
        SMALL_RECT srcWriteRect;

        coordinateBufferSize.Y = 5;
        coordinateBufferSize.X = 9;

        topLeftCoordinate.Y = 0;
        topLeftCoordinate.X = 0;

        (&srcWriteRect)->Top = 4;
        (&srcWriteRect)->Left = 10;
        (&srcWriteRect)->Bottom = 8;
        (&srcWriteRect)->Right = 18;

        HANDLE oldScreenBuffer = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        HANDLE newScreenBuffer = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
            GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
            FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
            NULL,
            CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
            NULL);

        BOOL succes = WriteConsoleOutputW(
            newScreenBuffer,                    // The new ScreenBuffer
            map,                                // The char array we want to display
            coordinateBufferSize,               // 
            topLeftCoordinate,
            &srcWriteRect
        );

        SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(newScreenBuffer);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to @AsteroidsWithWings for asking me for a 'minimal reproducible example' and pointing me to the debugger, this was information that will help me for many years to come!

Comment: Yes, this is the answer, and yes a MCVE would have led you to the solution ;) Notice that the real problem had nothing to do (directly) with `j` or `static int` in a loop - that was just a side effect of your program's undefined behaviour. Have fun!